# Increment cell value per section UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which generates its data from a pList.

I have a method `configureCell` which setups each cell so it will display the label and a coloured block next to it.

The label of each cell however needs to increment per section. So each section starts with 0 and increases in .5 steps each time.

I've tried running this on `configureCell` but it updates **every** time the cell is scrolled back into view.

What's the best way of doing this? The value will never change and is always .5 increments.

Comment: When you say the label increments, do you mean you are showing a number in the label which needs to increase by 0.5 for each cell?

Comment: For each row. Then resets every time it makes a new section. 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your label is called 'label' you can set it like so:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%0.1f", ((float)indexPath.row / 2.0)];
```

Comment: Woohoo! I was so close. I was using *another* variable to count. I didn't actually realise and process the fact that `indexPath.row` restarts its count each section. :)